# ¿Cómo se puede usar las dos columnas de resultado de un SELECT en un UPDATE en SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Basicamente mi problema es que tengo una consulta bastante compleja para poder obtener la suma de productos que vendio cada  empleado, la cual es la siguiente:

```
SELECT SUM(Quantity)AS productosven, EmployeeID FROM(SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.EmployeeID,[Order Details].Quantity 
    FROM Orders  INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
    ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID)AS X
GROUP BY EmployeeId
```

El resultado de la consulta anterior es:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y es necesaria que sea así de compleja, ya que en la tabla Orders tengo el OrderID y el EmployeeID y en la tabla [Order Detail] tengo el OrderID y la cantidad de producto.

Lo que hace es obtenerme dos columnas en las cuales de un lado tengo todos los productos que ese empleado vendió y del otro obtengo el id de ese empleado, y ahora intento meter eso en un update, de la siguiente manera:

```
UPDATE DimEmployee 
SET N_Productos =(SELECT SUM(Quantity)AS productosven, EmployeeID FROM(SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.EmployeeID,[Order Details].Quantity 
        FROM Orders  INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
        ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
        ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID)AS X
    GROUP BY EmployeeId) 
WHERE 
EmployeeID=(SELECT EmployeeID FROM(SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.EmployeeID,[Order Details].Quantity 
        FROM Orders  INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
        ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
        INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
        ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID)AS X
    GROUP BY EmployeeId)
```

Pero  me dice que no es posible ya que devuelve varios resultados, me imagino que es por que uso la misma consulta dos veces, una en el set y otra en el where, pero no se.

```
UPDATE DimEmployee SET N_Productos =(SELECT SUM(Quantity)AS productosven, EmployeeID FROM(SELECT Orders.OrderID,Orders.EmployeeID,[Order Details].Quantity 
    FROM Orders  INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
    ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
    INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
    ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID)AS X
GROUP BY EmployeeId)
```

Y de esta forma me aparece este error:

> Mens. 116, Nivel 16, Estado 1, Línea 7 Sólo se puede especificar una
>   expresión en la lista de selección cuando la subconsulta no se
>   especifica con EXISTS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En SQLServer puedes hacer una consulta de actualización, algo bastante útil, conceptualmente es algo así:

```
UPDATE Tabla1
       SET Columna = T2.OtraColumna
       FROM Tabla1 T1
       INNER JOIN Tabla2 T2
          ON T1.AlgunId = T2.AlgunId
```

Si te fijas bien es casi una consulta habitual a la que se le ha agregado las sentencias de `UPDATE`. Adaptando un poco tu consulta, podrías hacer algo así:

```
UPDATE  DimEmployee
        SET N_Productos = G.productosven
        FROM DimEmployee E
        INNER JOIN (SELECT  SUM(Quantity) AS productosven, 
                            EmployeeID 
                            FROM (SELECT Orders.OrderID,
                                        Orders.EmployeeID,
                                        [Order Details].Quantity 
                                        FROM Orders  
                                        INNER JOIN DimEmployee 
                                        ON Orders.EmployeeID=DimEmployee.EmployeeID 
                                        INNER JOIN [Order Details] 
                                        ON [Order Details].OrderID=Orders.OrderID
                            ) X
                            GROUP BY EmployeeId
        ) G
        ON E.EmployeeID = G.EmployeeID
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, no sabe cuanto le agradezco, ya que los ejemplos que hay en internet suelen ser muy vagos al respecto.